# Blood as newtonian flow and Poiseuille law

Tags: physiology, homework

For a prep exam:

A healtly pacient has a carotid with the following characteristics:

intern ratio: = 2.8 mm, 
2 = 89 , 
1 = 90 ,
 blood = 3.5 cp,
=10.0 cm.

Using the following equations calculate:

$$V(r)=\frac{P_1 - P_2}{4 \mu L}R^2 [1-(\frac{r}{R})^2]$$
$$V_{max}= V(r=0)$$
$$\overline{V} = \frac{Q}{A}=\frac{1}{2}V_{max}$$
$$Q=\frac{\pi(P_1 - P_2)}{8 \mu L}R^4$$

where P_1 and P_2 are the mean pressure to in and out the vase, R is ve vase radius, L is the length of the vase segment and $\mu$ is the viscosity of the fluid.

A healthy patient has a carotid withe the following characteristics: intern radius R = 2.8 mm, $P_2$ = 89 mmHg, $P_1$ = 90 mmHg, $\mu_{blood}$=3.5cp, L = 10cm.

Using the previous equations calculate:

a) Mean velocity on the carotid artery Rta: 0.372 m/s
b) Maximum velocity Rta: 0.744 m/s
c) caudal on the carotid artery Rta: $9.16x10^{-6} m^{-6}$

I have tried to solve this problem but when i try to replace changing the units to the adecuate I have not the correct answer

Comment: could you please elaborate on how you went about solving it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for physics.SE.